# If.. else: Is there a better way to handle this?

Tags: python

I have a file manipulation that needs to be done if the file does not exist or is empty, otherwise just read the file.  I can do this with something like:

```
def Write_File():
    [some code to write the file]

Exists = os.path.exists('filename')
if Exists:
    Fsize = os.path.getsize('filename')
    if Fsize > 0:
        [some code to read the file]
    else:
        Write_File()
else:
    Write_File()
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: `if os.path.exists(...) and os.path.getsize(...) > 0:`?

Comment: You could also put the condition in a function if it's a common idiom.

Comment: Presuming Python executes the tests left to right and stops execution if the first test fails, this would work.  Are both of these the case for Python?

Comment: Yes. Both of those are the case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first idea was to try `getsize` and catch the exception instead of testing if the file exists, with a default file size to 0.

But `getsize` returns 0 if the object is a directory. So you want to test the object type too (using `os.path.isdir()`). Using a lot of `os` calls costs time, specially on slow filesystems, so the fastest way is with `stat` which gets all the information in one system call.

```
import stat,os
filename = 'filename'
fsize = 0
try:
   sobj = os.stat(filename)
   if stat.S_ISDIR(sobj.st_mode):
      raise Exception("{} is a directory, cannot continue".format(filename))
   fsize = sobj.st_size
except OSError:
    pass

if fsize:  # we can omit > 0, fsize cannot be negative
    [some code to read the file]
else:
    Write_File()
```

in the snippet above, `fsize` is greater than 0 only if the file exists and is really a file. If the file doesn't exist, we write it, and if there's a directory with the same name, the program stops, as it's not possible to overwrite it/create a file with this name

Comment: I think this is the best solution.  Thanks!  In this particular case, I know a-priori the file is not a directory, so I can eliminate the try.  In general, of course, your code is more complete.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
import os

def write_file(filename)
    [some code to write the file]

def read_file(filename)
    [some code to read the file]

filename = 'path/to/filename'


try:
    if os.path.exists(filename) and os.stat(filename).st_size > 0:
       # file exists and not empty
       read_file(filename)
    else:
       print('file doesnot exists')
       write_file(filename)
except OSError as e:
       # error generated because of trying to get size of a non-existent file 
       print(e)
```

Comment: Yes, that is what jonrsharpe suggested in his comment above.  As I responded, this will work only if Python executes the tests left to right and stops execution if the first test fails. Not all interpreters do this.  Are both of these the case for Python?

Comment: `and` short circuits, fortunately.

Comment: @Irhorer, I added exception handling. It will now handle the case when python executes the test from right to left. In that case, you can write your logic inside except module.